# Object, entities, pocos, models etc

Tags: model, poco, entities

I have seen these terms used interchangebly on the web for objects (.Net). Could someone explain the difference between them.

- POCO
- Entity
- Model
- Domain Object
- Active Record

Are Entities and POCO the same/similar?

I normally think as Model objects as being part of the UI layer of an N-Tier architecture, is this correct?

Are there any other "names" for such objects?

These are very broad questions I understand but I am aware is a broad subject!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

1. POCO - Plain Old C# Object, follows after [Martin Fowler's POJO](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html) for Plain Old Java Object.  It was a reaction against EJB 2.0, which required two interfaces and extending a class just to express an entity EJB.  The idea of POJO/POCO emphasizes creating domain objects as instances of classes, not requiring heavy framework machinery.
2. Entity - This is a synonym for a persistent object to me.  The Java Enterprise Java Bean spec divides the world into entity, stateless session, stateful session, and message driven beans.  Session beans are like services - functional objects that implement useful business logic.  Message driven beans are associated with queues and perform asynchronous logic.
3. Model - Union of all your domain objects; may or may not be POCOs/POJOs.
4. Domain Object - This is an abstract idea for an object that describes the business problem you're trying to solve.  See [Eric Evans' "Domain Driven Design"](http://books.google.com/books?id=7dlaMs0SECsC&dq=domain+driven+design&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=SS9GTLDNC8Kblgee6ujwAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false).
5. Active Record - Another [Martin Fowler term from PEAA](http://books.google.com/books?id=FyWZt5DdvFkC&lpg=PA1&dq=Patterns%20of%20Enterprise%20Application%20Architecture%20by%20Martin%20Fowler&pg=PT187#v=onepage&q=active%20record&f=false); it's a wrapper for a database row that adds logic.

Comment: [Alternative intepretion of POCO = Plain old CLR object. Occasionally you also see PONO (Plain old .net object).]